# Rails: render partial partially

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a main file, `home.html.erb` and inside I'm rendering around 15 partials. These partials are quite small and I was wondering if it's possible to put them all inside one file and then render partially the partial.

For example, I would make `_big_partial.html.erb` which would contain many divs/sections/ids, and in my `home.html.erb` I would write something like `<%= render partial: "big_partial.div" %>` (just an example, I know this doesn't work) to render that particular div.

I don't want to use jquery for this. I'm happy the way it is now, I just want to reduce the number of files and learn something new.

Comment: "I just want to reduce the number of files" - many small files are good. Easy to understand individually. People are trying to break God objects into smaller pieces all the time. You, on the other hand, want to _create_ a god partial. Bad idea. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : I think reducing the number of partials reduces the page load time.

Comment: @webster: valid hypothesis, but it needs to be measured. Also, I bet that in any non-trivial app, the overhead of rendering a partial is completely dwarved by cost of, say, DB queries on the page (this needs to be measured too).

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your opinions and tips.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**_big_partial.html.erb**

```
<% if partial_number == 1 %>
  <%# render some div or section %>
<% elsif partial_number == 2 %>
  <%# render some div or section %>
<% end %>
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "big_partial", partial_number: 1 %>
```